# After successfull ajax call anchor tag's href attribute doesnt works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have these

```
    <div id="shelf">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="new-shelf-text" onkeyup="(this.value).trim().length?$('#add-shelf-btn').removeClass('disabled'):$('#add-shelf-btn').addClass('disabled');" placeholder="Add new shelf">
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="add-shelf-btn" class="button postfix disabled">Add</div>
    </div>

    <a class="shelfName" href="#shelF"> Shelf Lists </a>

    <div id="shelF" class="content">
      welcome in shelf listing      
    </div>   
    </div>
    <script>

    $("#add-shelf-btn").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url 'shelf' groupid %}",
      datatype: "html",
      data:{
        shelf_name: $('#new-shelf-text').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#shelf").html(data);
      }
    });

    });

    </script>
```

when i click on link (anchor tag) mentioned above after successfull ajax return it doesnt calls the "div" whose id is "shelF"
Can any one help me ,i want to call the

```
<div id="shelF" class="content">
```

on click of link

```
<a class="shelfName" href="#shelF"> Shelf Lists </a>
```

Remember it works fine for first time , but when it returns from successfull ajax call that div doesnt get called.

Comment: how can a div be called?

Comment: `$("#shelf").html(data);` and `<div id="shelF"` dont match.

Comment: In your html you have id as "**shelF**" and you are inserting data in the id "**shelf**"(small "f") which doesn't exist. try changing:
$("#shelf").html(data); with this $("#shelF").html(data);

Comment: Phylax & Vishal , look at the code once again and now tell me ,my question is i want to call `<div id="shelF" class="content">` on click of link `<a class="shelfName" href="#shelF"> Shelf Lists </a>` , as i told it works for first time, as a simple html , but when i  click on `<div id="add-shelf-btn" class="button postfix disabled">Add</div>` it goes for ajax call , and when it returns successfully , the div which i want to call `<div id="shelF" class="content">` on click of `<a class="shelfName" href="#shelF"> Shelf Lists </a>` doesnt works. Now i hope you got my problem

Comment: Guys please suggest an answer , I got stucked here since from 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for your trigger:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add-shelf-btn", function() {code...})
```

Comment: Bradley , please look at the above comments which i told to phylax & Vishal ,so that you will get clear with exact problem and look at the code once again, and help me out.

Comment: I'm still confused, so your ajax call works but the div is not loading? or the div is loading and you want to setup another click handler to show something else after it returns the div?

Comment: Yes , ajax call works, even div is also getting loaded with new contents, but when i refresh the page then only the contents will displayed in that div. So after ajax loads the contents, `<a class="shelfName" href="#shelF"> Shelf Lists </a>` this link doesnt works, means `<div id="shelF" class="content">`this div doesnt gets called. But When i refresh the page then only `<a class="shelfName" href="#shelF"> Shelf Lists </a>` this link works.

Comment: are you loading that div from a seperate file? or is it just hidden on the page?

Comment: No, that div is from the same file, and also its not hidden on page

Comment: Your just trying to make an anchor work, just realized that. Have you tried playing with document.location.hash? or you could even do a jquery on click function and utilize .scroll

Comment: No , i havent did that, but what the use of it , and how i can use this `document.location.hash`

Comment: The scroll on click will be easier, here is a code snippet that animates it as well, $(document).on("click", #shelF, function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".shelfName").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});